# How to load all tabs eagerly on startup?

Tags: google-chrome

After restarting Chrome with my computer, I am frequently interrupted by a tab loading that has not been loaded in background. This is needlessly distracting, as my machines all have plenty of hardware resources. Therefore, I want Google Chrome to load all my tabs on startup. How can I configure or otherwise enforce this behavior of eagerly loading all tabs on startup?

Answer (score 3):

A workaround is to press and hold `Ctrl` + `Tab` to cycle through the tabs. This will trigger loading each of them. After completing one round, click on the previously active tab again to restore state.